# How to fix Ensure text remains visible during webfont load Nuxtjs?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using nuxtjs in my app. And using custom 'Avenir';
I want to improve my lighthouse score regarding this msg - "Ensure text remains visible during webfont load" .
Also, I am not including the fonts from my nuxt.config.js.

My fonts are in ~assets/fonts/AvenirReg.ttf

Comment: Did you find a solution?